# Xcode 7.0.1 coreplot 2.0 Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'

Tags: ios, xcode7

I'm a newbie in Xcode, I need help in debugging an existing code written in older version Xcode and coreplot. I'm currently using Xcode 7.0 and coreplot 2.0. I'm getting error message

> Sending `NSDecimal` to parameter of incompatible type `NSNumber * _Nonnull`

at the following code:

```
thePlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger([xArray count]+1+1)];

thePlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(countGraphNames+1)];
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to upgrade to CorePlot 2.x and change the call `CPTDecimalFromFloat` to `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]`.

Comment: what about CPTDecimalFromString(@"7") ?